# How to provide access to users who are not added in list/groups of authorized users in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a SharePoint server 2013. And i have added site-pages in that, now i want the home page (www.xyz.com) to be accessible to all users regardless they have been added to the groups/authenticated users.

Except the home page the only the registered users should have access to content/other pages. Otherwise SharePoint should give a message you don't have access or **this page hasn't shared with you** when an unauthorized user tries to access the rest of the site-pages.

I already tried **NTAuthority command** to define setting on Home page but for that the user needs to have the exact path of the webpage (www.xyz.com/main.aspx) otherwise it's not working with just (www.xyz.com).
Either the user is getting all the access or none.

Kindly refer this link for more info. It is somewhat similar to what i need.

[Sharepoint-Add permission to to all authenticated users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/add-permission-to-all-authenticated-users)

Comment: Can you use asp_Membership logic to achieve this? Feasible one

Comment: Sorry i am new so could you plz give more details like the steps to do that?

Comment: You can refer documentation about asp.net membership over here http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs

Comment: I don't need authentication using credentials, the sharepoint has groups of user i want the check to be performed on basis of that.